# JQuery Mobile ListView filter working after pressing backspace

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am using Jquery Mobile ListView filter.

HTML Code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="ulBrands" data-corners="false" data-filter-placeholder="">
  <!-- list of "li" is dynamic -->
</ul>enter code here`
```

When I type "ab" then filter is now working, but when I press backspace then it's start showing the filter result.

What is the problem?

Comment: The widgets is programed to working after three keydown events.

Comment: In my case it's not working after three keydown events, but when I type two text and press one backspace then it starts working.

Comment: Then you have preformed three keydown events. Two letters and one space = three.

Comment: I am following this example as reference [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dLeUw/) but It's not working same as example.

Comment: In that demo it uses old version of JQM. Are you using 1.3?

Comment: I am using JQM version 1.3.2

Comment: That code won't work on 1.3.2, it needs to be modified.

Comment: Now I can understand the problem, when I am updating the JQM with 1.3.2 then same problem I can see in this example. I have updated the JSFiddle. See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dLeUw/38/). Now it's working only when I press backspace. So what is the solution?